# How do I block Unity from phoning home?

Tags: unity-games

It was recently announced that Unity will start charging game developers a fee for every Unity based game installed on the computer. Upon learning of this, I also learnt that Unity collects installation information from users, which in my mind is a form of telemetry data that I would rather not be giving away.

As a gamer, I would rather my computer was not phoning home to Unity. Which hosts do Unity Games phone home to? How can I block them from collecting telemetry in Windows Firewall?

Comment: It is probably agains the TOS of Unity to not let it phone home, which would run afoul of our rules here. But id need someone to point to me where in the TOS it does mention it. :p

Comment: I'm sure Unity has a developer-facing TOS, but does it also have an end-user-facing one?

Comment: Super User might be a more suitable site for these kind of questions (firewall configuration).

Comment: I agree this may be better scoped to super user, but it's definitely not a gamedev question.

Comment: @pppery `@Amarth I believe this question is off-topic at Super User. As stated in the [Super User Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), video games are considered off-topic there. On the other hand, this question seems to fit the scope of Arqade since it is not about game development. For this reason, I’m voting to keep this question open.

Comment: @Fredy31 Regarding TOSs and Arqade, see the [meta] post, [Is breaking a ToS\ToU agreement illegal, and if so, why do we support this?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6848/4797) '*In the past, the way I've approached these things is to ask "is there a reason why this question could/would be asked that appears valid? Can I assume good faith?" - if so, then I generally consider it safe. Then, I would answer with the caveat that "hey, I'm no expert, but I think it's possible that you could get into trouble with this if you used it in the wrong way."*'

Comment: @Fredy31 Actually, the internet is quite divided right now. Some claim that existing games can't have their ToS retroactively changed (would require at least an update and the player signing again, and trying to bruteforce them into signing to be able to continue playing the game would probably be a violation too) and any pre-existing ToS / License probably didn't include a "we can phone home" statement (especially since the same company stated in the past they would never do that). I still agree that this question is probably best for another site though.

Comment: also, before asking this question is probably better to check a) if they are legally allowed to harvest said that from the user, b) if the user is legally allowed to oppose that and c) if they were planning to collect the data from the user in the first place. Some articles claim they were planning to request the distribution platforms to provide the data (Steam, PSN Store, Nintendo E-Shop etc...)... and I hope that will end in them getting sued into oblivion like they deserve.